# WEKA - Compute an average number of non-missing attributes per class attribute

Tags: weka, missing-data

I'm working with a dataset with a lot of missing values. For analytical purposes, I want to be able to compute the average number of non-missing attributes assigned to each class label in the following manner.

Having data like

```
@relation class

@attribute one {1,2}
@attribute two {1,2}
@attribute three {1,2}
@attribute class {human, animal}

@data
1,Na,Na,human
1,1,Na,human
Na,Na,2,animal
```

I want to be able to obtain a result like this.

```
Average non-missing attributes per class label:
  - human = 1.5
  - animal = 1
```

Is there any way of doing this in the WEKA explorer?